# On a variant of Brocard's problem using the definition of Pochhammer symbols

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, divisors-multiples

I've considered the following variant of Brocard's problem $$\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n-1)!}+1=m^2\tag{1}$$
for integers $n\geq 1$ and integers $m\geq 1$. I was inspired from the fact that the evaluation of the Pochhammer symbol $(1)_n=n!$ (previous equation $(1)$ is to consider the specialization $x=n$ in $(x)_n+1=m^2$, where $(x)_n$ are the Pochhammer symbols defined as in the article *Pochhammer Symbol* from the online encyclopedia Wolfram MathWorld).

> **Question.** Is this problem known from literature? In this case please refers it, and I try to search and read about the solutions of $(1)$ over positive integers from the literature. In other case, is it possible to determine all the solutions of $$\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n-1)!}+1=m^2$$
>   for integers $n,m\geq 1$? **Many thanks.**

The only solution that I know is $(n,m)=(4,29)$, and I don't know if this problem is in the literature. I think that in the problem to determine all solutions should be useful Legendre's formula.

If a discussion using the abc-conjecture is feasible feel free to add it also as a part of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but note that the case $n=4$ comes from the identity $$\frac{(x+4)!}{x!} + 1 = (x^2+5x+5)^2 $$
Other examples where $x!/y!+1$ is a square include 
$$\eqalign{6!/3!+1 &= 11^2\cr
14!/7!+1 &= 4159^2\cr
57!/54!+1 &= 419^2\cr}
$$
There are no others with $2 \le y \le x \le 1000$ and $x-y \ne 4$ [EDIT:] or $1$.

[EDIT:] The case $x-y=3$ corresponds to an elliptic curve $y^3 + 6 y^2 + 11 y + 7 = s^2$, which (if I'm using Sage correctly) has integral points
$$(y,s) = (-3, \pm 1), (-2, \pm 1), (-1, \pm 1), (1, \pm 5), (3, \pm 11), (54, \pm 419)$$
The Sage code is

```
E = EllipticCurve([0,6,0,11,7]);
E.integral_points(both_signs=True)
```

Comment: Many thanks, this afternoon I am going to study your contribution. Many thanks again for your attention and mathematics.

Comment: $11, 419, 4159$ are all of the form $x^2+5x+5$ for some positive integer $x$.